# NSTabView Objects out of place on launch

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstabview

I've created an NSTabview with two tabs in interface builder. Added some objects (a line sone labels and a text field, codeed it and allworks as expected. Just on thing that i can't figure out. When i launch the app the objects that i placed manually in the view are not where they should be. they are slightly shifted out of place. when i click on the second tab and back they all move to their correct place. while the app is still running they will stay in place, but when i relaunch the app the same thing happens again. How can i track down the cause, I'm perplexed. it has to be something simple, but can't figure what it is. some help would be appreciated or hints

Comment: Do you place objects in the tab view or do you place objects in the view of a tab? Do you use autolayout?

Comment: I figured it out, autolayout was moving the objects because they were too close to the tab buttons. I turned autolayout off, locked the objects into position. then i subclassed the nsview to increase it's height so that the objects don't get clipped. thanks.